# visual studio 2010 control library references

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll

I wrote a control library using visual studio 2010, I'll call it MyLibrary. MyLibrary references another control library I have that we'll call AnotherLibrary.  I also have a clean virtual machine (CVM) and I've added AnotherLibrary to the GAC on the CVM.  Using the CVM, I create a new WinForms project, add MyLibrary.dll to the toolbox, and drop one of the controls onto the form. Visual Studio will add MyLibrary.dll AND AnotherLibrary.dll to the references, even though AnotherLibrary.dll is in the GAC (and isn't needed).  I can remove AnotherLibrary.dll from the references and everything is fine.

Is there a way to prevent visual studio from adding AnotherLibrary.dll in this scenario?

Edit: I've given this some thought and I have an example. When you add a TabControl to a parent control in the designer, visual studio won't add System.Design to the references, even though the TabControl depends on it. So, surely there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You still need the reference.  Just like you need the reference to, say, System.dll which is also in the GAC.  You just don't need the *copy* of the assembly in your bin\Debug directory.  That you happened to not break the compiler by removing the reference is possible, especially since is this is an indirectly used assembly.  But some odds that you'll eventually run out of luck.

In general you *really* want to avoid using the GAC on your dev machine.  Because you care about *specific* versions of an assembly when you, say, create a bug fix.  You get those specific versions from source control, not the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't it make sense that it would automatically include all dependencies? It cannot assume that AnotherLibrary is in the GAC on every machine you might want to deploy your code on.  Of course as you mentioned you can manually remove it....

Comment: I've seen this done before.  Let's say you release an SDK using a 3rd party library and you don't want your end user to have to add references to the 3rd party library. You can GAC the 3rd party .dlls in an installer and provide your .dll. Although your .dll references the 3rd party .dlls, the resulting .exe doesn't care about the other .dll until runtime.